# Silent login with facebook api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, react-native, oauth

I have an app that allows a user to login with facebook. Is there anyway to keep a device authorized. For example, every time a user needs to login with facebook they are routed to the facebook application, where they are then routed back to my app. Is there a way to check for an access token and not re-route the user. I am using expo-facebook package and react-native.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time when user wants to login with facebook then Routing to the facebook API is necessary its `official` in the FB API docs ! `But` on second attempt it will not redirects you to the facebook to get data ,it implies fetches the token and you can move on !

Comment: I understand that it fetches the access token on the second attempt, however, I am wondering if there is a way to check the token on my client instead of going to facebook, where it tells the user they're already logged in, where it then routes them back to my client.